# Undefined variable: all_data (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to post data from controller to view, basically when page loads user sees the form and when it get submits, it returns the data. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have tried the following to returns the data

Return methods tried:

```
return view('welcome',['all_data'=>$all_data]);
return view('welcome')->with('all_data', $all_data);
return view('welcome')->with('data', json_decode($data, true));
return View::make('welcome', array('all_data'=>$all_data));
```

Controller:

```
public function getStatus(Request $request){

//SQLQuery which returns $all_data

$all_data = json_encode($data);
return view('welcome', compact('all_data'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/getstatus', 'GetApplicationStatusController@getStatus');
```

View:

```
@foreach ($all_data as $data)
<td id="appid">{{$data->appid}}</td>
<td id="firstname">{{$data->firstname}}</td>
<td id="middlename">{{$data->middlename}}</td>
<td id="lastname">{{$data->lastname}}</td>
<td id="action">{{$data->action}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The get route you have defined is bypassing your controller.

Comment: Try `Route::get('/','Controller@getStatus');` instead

Comment: @bassxzero its not working getting the same error

Comment: what does `$all_data` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass all_data without json_encode for foreach

```
public function getStatus(Request $request){

    //SQLQuery which returns $data
    $all_data = $data;
    return view('welcome', compact('all_data'));
}
```

In view:

```
@foreach ($all_data as $data)
   <td id="appid">{{$data['appid']}}</td>
   <td id="firstname">{{$data['firstname']}}</td>
   <td id="middlename">{{$data['middlename']}}</td>
   <td id="lastname">{{$data['lastname']}}</td>
   <td id="action">{{$data['action']}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: getting error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: paste your get data query here

Comment: I'm getting data as I expected the problem is sending it on view

Comment: I have updated my code change in view file as per above

Answer (score 0):

my first thought is that you are visiting the / route, which doesn't have the variable all_data. to fix this just call the controller from this route as well: `Route::get('/', 'GetApplicationStatusController@getStatus')`

Comment: its not working getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`return view('welcome')->with(compact('all_data'));`
or this:
`return view('welcome')->with(['all_data'=>$all_data])`

Comment: getting error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/welcome.blade.php) with 2nd return statement

Comment: remove the `json_encode`, the view expects an array and no json

Comment: if I remove that it is giving error: Trying to get property of non-object